# Microsoft cntk sgd accepts larger learning rates than tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, cntk

I am training the same CNN architecture using cntk and tesnorflow. However when I'm using a larger learning rate such as 0.05 `cntk.sgd` is fine but `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` will result in `nan` values. I tried to debug both and I see that tensorflow is generating much larger outputs after the first iteration which is due to large weights in the network.

- Neither of the models use xavier initialization.
- Neither of the models use any batch normalization.
- Neither of the models use any gradient clipping. I even set the `gradient_clipping_with_truncation` to `False` for `cntk.sgd()`.
- I use `tf.layers.conv2d` for tensorflow and `cntk.layers.Convolution` for the cntk code:

Here is the pseudo code for tensorflow:

```
conv1_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=X_reshaped, filters=64, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
...
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=drop6, units=n_outputs, name="raw_outputs")
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=logits, onehot_labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss)
 _, batch_loss = sess.run([training_op, loss], feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch, training: True})
```

And here is the pseudo code for the cntk:

```
def cost_func(prediction, target):
train_loss = ct.negate(ct.reduce_sum(ct.element_times(target, ct.log(prediction)), axis=-1))

ct.layers.Convolution((3,3), [64,128][i], pad=True)
ct.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=None, name='output')
z = model.model(input_var)

train_loss = cost_func(training_mode, pred, label_var)
pe = ct.classification_error(z, label_var)

learner = ct.sgd(z.parameters, lr=0.05, gradient_clipping_with_truncation=False)
    trainer = ct.Trainer(z, (train_loss, pe), learner)

trainer.train_minibatch({input_var: images, label_var: labels})

training_loss += trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average * current_batch_size
```

**UPDATE:** so apparently outputs for both frameworks gets large in the final layer (e.g., 2.6e+09). So there is no truncation for sure for any of the models. Still investigating how cntk handles it but tf can't!